# Regex with unusual characters

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to come up with some regex to handle the # sign.

Example, #PRODUCT_143#

If the input were #PRODUCT_143, the regex `#PRODUCT_(\d*$)` matches and returns 143 as the match. But adding the # to the end of both the input and the regex causes it to break. what do I need to do here to get this to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tried `#PRODUCT_(\d*$)#` it’s no surprise that it didn’t found a match. Since the `$` already marks the end of the string and the `#` after it will never be matched.

So try this instead:

```
#PRODUCT_(\d*)#$
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't break anything, maybe you've forgotten to move the `$` in the regex, which means end of line? This regex should be fine:

```
#PRODUCT_(\d*)#$
```

(I'm not sure why you were capturing the end of line in your original regex).

Answer (score 1):

Did you just forget to move the `$` out of the parenthesis?

```
    ^#PRODUCT_([0-9]*)#$
```

Note the added `^` - may be it is not right for your input.

Answer (score 1):

The $ probably matches as the end-of-line, so your extra # is confusing it:

```
#PRODUCT_(\d*)#$
```